# Regex to add and replace parts of a URL

Tags: regex, facebook, url

I'm trying to help a buddy use his Facebook to post to his website. I've managed to make the posts from his wall's RSS feed, but in the feed any images show as tiny thumbnails.

The difference between a Facebook image thumbnail and its full sized counterpart is as follows:

thumb -https://fbcdn-photos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/378108_348325051862306_118443001517180_1297951_1051469646_s.jpg

full -https://fbcdn-sphotos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/**s720x720**/378008_348325051862306_118443001517180_1297951_1051469646_**n**.jpg

I've bolded the differences.

So I'm looking for a way to make that substitution, and I figured regex was the way, but couldn't wrap my head around something like this.

The answer and an explanation would be quite helpful. Thanks in advance.

edit: I would probably make the replacement in jQuery.

Comment: What API method is returning those? You should be able to just query for the larger URL instead. Edit your question to include some sample code and we should be able to show you which FQL table or API method can give you the correct image

Comment: Not using the API. I'm using an RSS feed directly from the Facebook page. Check any public Facebook page and in the bottom of the left column there's an RSS feed.

Comment: I would most likely use jQuery to replace the text in the URLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var thumb_url = 'https://fbcdn-photos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/378108_348325051862306_118443001517180_1297951_1051469646_s.jpg';

var full_url = thumb_url.replace(/(\/[^/]*)s\.jpg$/, '/s720x720$1n.jpg');
```

Explanation:

`/(\/[^/])s.jpg/` matches a forward slash `\/` followed by many non-forward slash characters `[^/]*` followed by s.jpg. It captures everything from the forward slash up to the s into $1.

Then it replaces the entire match:
 (in this case `/378108_348325051862306_118443001517180_1297951_1051469646_s.jpg`)

With: `/s720x720$1n.jpg` where `$1` is:

```
/378108_348325051862306_118443001517180_1297951_1051469646_
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. One last question: if I wanted to find all urls that matched this instead of specifically defining them as variables, could you tell me how to do that?

Comment: You're welcome. If you want an array of thumb urls and you have something like a string of XML you should use something like: `var urls = str.match(/https:\/\/fbcdn-photos-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-ash4\/[0-9_]*s.jpg/g);`

Comment: Not sure if the `akamaihd` or `hphotos-ak-ash4` can vary too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final solution I used, just in case anyone is interested. This will switch all images that are Facebook thumbnails from the RSS feed with their full sized counterparts:

```
$("img[src^='https://fbcdn-photos-a.akamaihd.net']")
.each(function()
{ 
  this.src = this.src.replace(/(\/[^/]*)s\.jpg$/, '/s720x720$1n.jpg');
});​
```

Comment: does this still work? as i think that fb have changed the way their image URLs work now.